# How to call an action method and pass array with using javascript in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to do when I click a button, this button pass the array's values from controller to the View. But how can I call controller action and pass array with using javascript ?

Here is my action method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()

        {
            TahakkukServicesClient client = new TahakkukServicesClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            MakbuzList[] liste = client.GetMakbuzListe(2);
            return View(liste);
        }
```

And my view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MakbuzList>
    @using icerik.TahakkukServices       

    @{

        ViewBag.Title = "E-Belediye";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Ecouncil.cshtml";

    }
    <script type="text/javascript">

        ????????????

</script>
    <li><a class="collapsed">Description</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Button1</a></li>

                    </ul>
               </li>
```

Comment: Poster removed original question and reposted the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Bind an onclick action to button, which fires ajax GET request to your Index method and parse the result. In your MVC Index action, instead returning ViewResult, return Json.
Like shown [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)